# How to get the selected index of <li> inside <ul> using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-lists, selectedindex

I used to do this for `<option>` selected:

```
var select_filter = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
if (select_filter && select_filter[select_filter.selectedIndex].value == 0) {
 ///...
}
```

but now I am using `<li>` elements inside `<ul>` , so how can I achieve the same like above?

**EDIT**
Added html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav-item" id="Driftcenter-nav-tav">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#Driftcenter"
            onclick="load_business_units(); showFilter();">Driftcenter</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="vognmaend-nav-tav">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#vognmaend"
            onclick="load_operation_carrier_list(); showFilter();">Vognmænd</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="ads-segment-nav-tav">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#ads-segment"
            onclick="load_ads_units(); showFilter();">ADS Segment</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="traffik-info-nav-tab">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#trafik-info"
            onclick="filterTrafficCondition(); hideFilter();">Trafikinfo</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="vejr-varsel-nav-tab">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#vejr-varsel"
            onclick="filterTrafficWeather(); hideFilter();">Vejrvarsel</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: there is no selected index of a unordered list.  if you are selecting one yourself, you are probably adding a class to it to mark it as selected, but as you haven't shown your code for that part, then this question is off topic for SO

Comment: One way of doing it would be adding a `class="selected"` attribute on click so that you can filter the items you want with `document.querySelectorAll('.selected')`

Comment: @secan how to check if any is selcted using document.querySelectorAll('.selected')?

Comment: if `document.querySelectorAll('.selected').length > 0` then there is one or more item selected. I put together a code snippet to see some potential uses: https://jsfiddle.net/kgd74fpv/

Comment: ... or, if you want to be more specific, `if (document.querySelectorAll(#myDropdown > li.selected).length > 0) { /* do what you want when at least one item is selected */ }`

Comment: @secan how to check if the selected value is = 0 ?

Comment: According to your code, you do not have any value; it is a list of links. If what you mean is that you want to check whether one *and only one* item is selected, instead of checking `if (document.querySelectorAll('.selected').length > 0) { ... }` you check `if (document.querySelectorAll('.selected').length === 1) { ... }`

Comment: @secan see element with `class="nav-link active"` , I want to check whether that one is selected or not. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with "*I want to check whether that one is selected or not*"? I assume the `active` class is set when the user clicks on the link therefore if it has the `active` class it is selected; why should you check? On a side note, I'd suggest a slightly different approach to keep concerns separated; something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jrvk0Le3/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below example to get the index of clicked list item

```js
const ulList = document.getElementById("ul-ele");
const li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var nodes = Array.from( ulList.children );
let selected = -1;
document.getElementById("ul-ele").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
        if (selected !== nodes.indexOf(e.target)) {
            selected = nodes.indexOf(e.target);
            console.log(selected);
        } else {
            console.log("Already selected");
        }
        
});
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <ul id="ul-ele">
   <li>Index 1</li>
   <li>Index 2</li>
   <li>Index 3</li>
   <li>Index 4</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But how can I just check of there is anything selected at all without adding any events priory ?

Comment: make a variable name `selected` and update it's value when `selected`. It shouldn't be same as already selected value

Comment: I am not trying to change its selected value, I am just trying to understand if there is anything selected at all

Comment: Then you can add a class `selected` on li for selected element and loop the `node` to check in which li does the class `selected` exists.

Comment: sorry for asking again, but can you take a look at the edited question? I have added the html and now each <li> contains an <a> element.